# What is the name of this device?

Tags: midi, sound-devices, controller

I would like to purchase a similar device, but I do not understand how it is called correctly. I suspect this is some kind of MIDI controller, but what exactly is it called? If you know, would be grateful to know the model

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an Avid S1.  Fader control surface or DAW controller would be some general search terms.